# Jenkins Build fails while compiling java code using Maven

Tags: maven, deployment, jenkins

I have a Java application and I am able to compile it using maven on CLI, I have a couple of build scripts to deploy the Java code to a remote server and compile the code using Maven but unfortunately the build fails while compiling it using my build script for Jenkins. When I try to compile the code on the remote server the build is successful. The error log is as follows:

```
[WARNING] The POM for org.im4java:im4java:jar:1.3.2 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for com.aliyun:aliyun-openservices:jar:1.0.0-20120705 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] GuestPath Project ................................. SUCCESS [5.183s]
[INFO] guestchat biz module .............................. FAILURE [4.001s]
[INFO] GuestChat Web Common .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] GuestChat Portal Webapp ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] guestchat openapi Webapp .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] guestchat chat server ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] guestchat service dashboard Webapp ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 10.518s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Sep 19 10:49:39 CST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/23M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project guestchat-biz:
Could not resolve dependencies for project com.guestops.guestchat:guestchat-biz:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:
The following artifacts could not be resolved:
org.im4java:im4java:jar:1.3.2, com.aliyun:aliyun-openservices:jar:1.0.0-20120705:
Failure to find org.im4java:im4java:jar:1.3.2 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until
the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

I hope I am being clear enough, any help is highly appreciated. I can provide with more details if needed..Thanks in advance!

Comment: try doing a mvn clean install

Comment: Tried doing that already, I get the same error!Has it got do something with the security as its deploying and compiling on a remote system? as I dont have nay problem compiling on the remote system manually. Thanks for the response though

Comment: the .pom file corresponding to the library mentioned in the question is not available in the repository. If it's not there, it would try to download it, else it would fail.

Comment: @asgs Yeah I understood that but why woudl it happen when I am using jenkins to deploy and compile and not when I run "mvn compile" on the remote system?

Comment: you say locally it compiles, right? Then, go to the build configuration on Jenkins and check the "Poll SCM" option to do polling on every build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should try to do the following:

1. Try to compile the project locally but make sure you're downloading the artifacts from the maven repository. Radically you can do it by renaming your ~user/.m2/repository and running ''mvn clean install''
2. If it compiles - your local maven is configured properly and its not a pom.xml issue. Also the remote repositories are configured right in maven. In this case its a jenkins issue or rather the issue of maven installed on the same machine with jenkins or maybe some network/security related issue (like a connection to the remote repository is firewalled and not accessible from the jenkins machine and so on).

I would suggest to check out the repository configuration on that maven, or if you want checkout the source code of your project on the jenkins machine and manually run the first step described above from that machine. You should see that the code can't be compiled and get the same error you're getting now.

Now if in during the step 1 the project can't be compiled - its just because you have had a dependency on the lacking module and they were somehow presenting in your local repository (I assume previously it could be compiled locally) and since we're kind of running a clean installation the local repository 'gets purged'. In this case you should find out where do your dependencies come from.
Things like

mvn dependency:tree on the failing module

Can be helpful here.

Hope this will help somehow

Comment: Finally figured it out, it was a security issue..Thanks so mcuh for your help!

Comment: @Uday a security issue? could you detail the answer also in here? The information presented here does not imply to a security issue in any way.

Answer (score 0):

2 possible quick solutions:

1. If it compiles locally, then go to the build configuration on Jenkins and check the "Poll SCM" option to do polling on every build.
2. Run from the command line on Jenkins server `mvn clean install` and make sure that the artifacts are available in maven repository after the build. If they are not, download the jars of the relevant versions and put them in the local maven repository (on Jenkins server).

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks everyone for the instant answers

Answer (score 0):

This is what the error message tells you:

> The following artifacts could not be resolved:
>   org.im4java:im4java:jar:1.3.2,
>   com.aliyun:aliyun-openservices:jar:1.0.0-20120705: Failure to find
>   org.im4java:im4java:jar:1.3.2 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2

So you have references in your pom for im4java 1.3.2 and aliyun-openservices 1.0.0-20120705, but these cannot be found in the general maven repo. If you do a [search for im4java in mvnrepository.com](http://mvnrepository.com/search.html?query=im4java), you'll see that [it only has version 1.2](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.im4java/im4java), so it is reasonable that it would fail. aliyun-openservices package doesn't exist there at all.

So, where should those be found? Maybe you have installed them locally only and not to Jenkins machine?

What you can do then, is either

1. (recommended) set up an intranet maven repo where you would deploy the needed libraries and reference that or
2. install them locally on the machine running Jenkins

Both of these should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

A quick look on [maven repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.im4java/im4java), only version 1.2.0 is available and not version 1.3.2 (which you are using).

Does your code compile with a maven build?

I suggest you try to review the repository setting on the jenkins instance